# Failed to authenticate credentials using Mongolite R

Tags: r, mongodb, heroku

I use R and trying to use the very recent "Mongolite". However I cannot connect to MongoDB server.
The manual clearly states the following:

```
mongo(collection = "test", db = "test", url = "mongodb://localhost")
```

This is what I have tried without success, where I have a log token and the port of course.

```
mongodb://heroku:TOKEN@lennon.mongohq.com:PORT
```

and keep getting the following error:

```
Error in mongo_collection_new(url, db, collection) : 
  Failed to authenticate credentials.
```

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the source code of jeroenooms/mongolite you can see that it doesn't support authentication yet:

https://github.com/jeroenooms/mongolite/blob/master/R/mongo.R

```
mongo_collection_new <- function(uri = "mongodb://localhost", db = "test", collection = "test"){
 stopifnot(is.character(uri))
 stopifnot(is.character(db))
 stopifnot(is.character(collection))
 .Call(R_mongo_collection_new, uri, db, collection)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is tried and true that **mongolite** (v0.7 as of today) supports authenticated connection to a *remote* 3.2.x MongoDB (as opposed to *localhost*).

The example below jeroenooms provides himself worked:

```
library(mongolite)
mongo(collection = "mtcars", url = "mongodb://readwrite:test@ds043942.mongolab.com:43942/jeroen_test")
```

To explain:

- `mtcars` is the name of the MongoDB "collection" (or "table" if you insist). It could be a name that does not exist yet.
- `readwrite` is the user name of your mongodb
- `test` is the password of the user "readwrite"
- `ds043942.mongolab.com` is the remote host, which could be replaced by ip address, i.e. 23.20.234.21
- `43942` is the port number. By default in MongoDB, it is 27017
- `jeroen_test` is the name of the database instance in use, which has to exist already

Running the commands above in R will print:

> Mongo Message: SCRAM: authenticating "readwrite" (step 1)
>
> Mongo Message: SCRAM: authenticating "readwrite" (step 2)
>
> Mongo Message: SCRAM: authenticating "readwrite" (step 3)
>
> Mongo Message: SCRAM: "readwrite" authenticated
>
> ...

---

I tried to replace it with my own remote host info. It didn't work in the beginning, which turned to be the user role issue rather than **mongolite** issue. After ensuring a user with correct readWrite roles, I connected to my remote 3.2.x MongoDB via **mongolite** package.

The following 2 sources were of great help to me in setting up users in MongoDB:

- [enable-authentication](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/)
- [Manage User and Roles](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/)

Answer (score 0):

just change the order :

**mongo( url = "mongodb://localhost",db = "test",collection = "test")**

Comment: Welcome to stack oveflow! While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run. [Reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following command allowed me to connect to mongodb using mongolite and the legacy SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication mode.

```
library(mongolite)
mongoUrl <- "mongodb://a_username:a_password@localhost:27017/admin" #<-admin here is the mongodb database that stores the authentication info

# specify your collection
colname <- "a_collection"

# specify your database
dbname <- "a_database"

# create connection (con)
con <- mongo(collection = colname, url = mongoUrl, db=dbname)

# count how many records (fyi this is just a test)
con$count('{}')
```